# How to store id and put to the end of foreach loop php

Tags: php

I'm looking for a solution to put a specified id to the end of loop.

Main problem, the ids are not alwasy in DESC order or ASC, so i cannot use this condition.

```
$array = array(
  'id' => 3,
  'id' => 4,
  'id' => 2,
  'id' => 8
);

$specifiedId = 2; //can be 3, 4 or 8, it depends on what user define

foreach($array as $data){
 if($data->id == $specifiedId){
   //store this id and move to the end of loop, do nothing yet
 }
 //do the job for id 3 4 and 8, update some data let say...
 ...
 //Ok, i have updated the data on id 3 4 and 8, now lets update the data for the $specifiedId
}
```

Is there a way to put that specified id to the end of loop?

Any help/hint is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Try this

```
<?php
$array = array(3,4,2,8);
$specifiedId = 2;
$t = count($array);
foreach($array as $key => $data){
 if($data == $specifiedId){
   $desired_id = $key;
 }
 if($key == $t - 1){//last iteration of the loop
 //now use your $desired_id here as reuired
  $desired_id;

 }
}
?>
```

Comment: I would also add a break after the line " $desired_id = $key; " which breaks out of the foreach once the value is found.

Comment: Good, that is not a problem to get the Desired if from Loop, what i want is to put at the end of loop,i mean inside of the loop but at the end, do the job with the first ids, then do the job for the desired_id. Thx

Comment: Then your example is not clear as to what you want to do after the IF in the loop.

Comment: maybe is not clear, but as you can write, end of loop, now lets use the $speficiedId and do the job, but inside of the loop. Thx

Comment: Is ok the conception, but tehnically i think it cannot be used, because it will pass trough each id, and at the end how can i get the stored id ?

Comment: print `$desired_id` you will get the ID

Answer (score 0):

You can just save the item from your array in a variable if it is found during the loop, then do the operation on that variable after the loop is finished.

```
$specifiedId = 2; //can be 3, 4 or 8, it depends on what user define

$specific_object = null;
foreach ($array as $data) {
    if ($data->id == $speficiedId) {
        //store this id and move to the end of loop, do nothing yet
        $specific_object = $data;
    } else {
        //do the job for id 3 4 and 8, update some data let say...        
        do_something_with($data);
    }
}
//Ok, i have updated the data on id 3 4 and 8, now lets update the data for the $speficiedId
if ($specific_object) do_something_with($specific_object);
```